# Disable Rule which is causing a redirect loop

Tags: 7, rules

I have created a rule for logged in members that if they go to the home page it redirects them to a different page. The home page needs to be different for anonymous and authenticated users.

One problem is that my rule is not working. I have created a redirect loop by mistake. This means I can not get to the rules interface to disable the module. I know I could disable the rules module via drush however I will have the same problem when I turn it back on.

I had a quick look in db and see the rules_rules table. However the data is stored as a blob so I can not edit it. Except for deleting my rules what could I do to disable it?

Comment: It always redirects, whatever page you're on?

Comment: Yep. The rule I set up ended matching all pages rather than the home page. So all pages for authenticated users cause a redirection loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a few options.

- You can try to edit the data by deserializing it with PHP and try to get some meaning out of it. Most likely there is a status which is either 1 or 0.
- You could delete the rule from the database entirely.
- You can temporarily modify the `rules_invoke_event` (`rules.module` line 249 for 1.4), if you comment out the `call_user_func_array` call, no rule should be invoked on the site.

Either of these should work, personally I would go for the last one if I had write access to the rules files.

Comment: /sites/all/modules/rules/rules/rules.module Worked for me on D6. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Rules 7.x-2.6:

- In the rules_config table set the active column to 0 for the problematic rule
- Empty/Truncate the cache_rules table

Answer (score 0):

They way i did to revert reload in one of my drupal 6 project.

1. logged in using ssh to the terminal.
2. logged in to database.
3. selected database.
4. goto rules_rules table.
5. written sql quary to delete affcting rule.

Answer (score 0):

[Devel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module has a nifty setting for this. Install devel module and visit `devel/settings`, enable the option `Display redirection page`.

As the description says

> When a module executes drupal_goto(), the query log and other
>   developer information is lost. Enabling this setting presents an
>   intermediate page to developers so that the log can be examined before
>   continuing to the destination page.

you can visit the intermediate page in-spite of the redirection.